# Utility to list and modify kernel modules loaded at system startup

Tags: linux, rhel, linux-kernel

How do I list all kernel modules loaded while system startup? Is there a user space utility to list and modify the modules loaded during system startup?

I am working on RHEL6 Desktop and RHEL6 Server.

List ftp modules compiled into kernel

```
  modprobe -l | grep ftp
     kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_ftp.ko
     kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tftp.ko
     kernel/net/netfilter/ipvs/ip_vs_ftp.ko
     kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_nat_ftp.ko
     kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_nat_tftp.ko
```

**Before boot:**

I unloaded 'nf_conntrack_ftp' module before system boot manually (using modprobe -r) and persistently across boot (by removing any shell script in /etc/sysconfig/modules/*.modules that loads kernel modules using /sbin/modprobe utility).

```
modprobe -rv nf_conntrack_ftp
lsmod | grep ftp
ls /etc/sysconfig/modules
init 6
```

**After boot:**

**RHEL6 Desktop** automatically loads 'nf_conntrack_ftp' module, but RHEL6 server does not.

```
lsmod | grep ftp
      nf_conntrack_ftp       12913  0 
      nf_conntrack           79758  5 nf_conntrack_ipv4,xt_conntrack,nf_conntrack_ftp,nf_conntrack_ipv6,xt_state


ls /sys/module/ | grep ftp
    nf_conntrack_ftp
```

In contrast to RHEL6 server, the RHEL6 Desktop indicates the 'nf_conntrack_ftp' module was loaded during system startup, which was verified by as above.

How do I list and modify all kernel modules configured for loading during system startup?